# Hopf algebra antipodes and right left comodule equivalences

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Given a Hopf algebra $H$, denote by ${}^H\mathrm{mod}$ the category of left $H$-comodules, and by $\mathrm{mod}^H$ the category of right $H$-comodules. If the antipode $S$ of $H$ is invertible then we have an equivalence between ${}^H\mathrm{mod}$ and $\mathrm{mod}^H$. What happens in the other direction? If we have an equivalence between ${}^H\mathrm{mod}$ and $\mathrm{mod}^H$ does this imply that the antipode is invertible? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: I don't think so, any coalgebra anti-automorphism will give you such an equivalence. In particular, unless I'm missing something you'll have such an equivalence if H is a cocommutative bialgebra even if it doesn't have an antipode at all.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense!